# Arduino controller and serial port with C# , weird characters pulling though serial port

Tags: c#, arduino

Im trying to read the port COM3 with C# serialport class.

When reading from serial port occasional weird characters is pulling from the serial port ?

Why is this problem occurring?

[image]

```
            foreach (USBDeviceInfo info in devices)
            {
                if (info.Description.Contains("Arduino"))
                {
                    Name = info.Description;
                    if (info.PnpDeviceID.Contains("(COM"))
                    {
                        ComPort = info.PnpDeviceID.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0];
                        using (SerialPort Port = new SerialPort())
                        {
                            Port.BaudRate = 9600;
                            Port.PortName = ComPort;

                            //rt.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
                            try
                            {
                                if (!Port.IsOpen)
                                    Port.Open();
                                string output = Port.ReadTo("end");

                                Value = output;
                                Port.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Value = ex.Message;
                            }
                            // this.SetText(message);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Controller code

```
    #include <OneWire.h>

 int SensorPin = 7;


 OneWire ds(SensorPin);

 void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
 }

void loop(void) {
    float temp = getTemp();

    Serial.println(temp);
    Serial.println("end");

    delay(100);

}


float getTemp(){


    byte data[12];
    byte addr[8];

    if (!ds.search(addr)) {
        //no more sensors on chain, reset search
        ds.reset_search();
        return -1000;
    }

    if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
        Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");


return -1000;
}

if (addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
    Serial.print("Device is not recognized");
    return -1000;
}

ds.reset();
ds.select(addr);
ds.write(0x44, 1);

byte present = ds.reset();
ds.select(addr);
ds.write(0xBE);


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    data[i] = ds.read();
}

ds.reset_search();

byte MSB = data[1];
byte LSB = data[0];

float TRead = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
float Temperature = TRead / 16;

return Temperature;
```

}

Comment: Can you tell what the value of this byte is?

Comment: water temp in adruino serial monitor stays constent, no bad values. But look at my monitor image above . It goes from 19.56 to 9.56?5

Comment: so for each value you open the port, read the string until "end" is received and close it back? what if you open it right when "end" is being sent, or in the middle of the number?

Comment: What I was asking for was the byte value (binary) so for example an string "1" has one byte with the value 49 or 0x31. The ? may be anything and just printed this way because it is an unknown/non printable character.